# How to generate schema with openapi_extra and BaseModel.model_json_schema in FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

My code (pydantic v1.10):

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Department(BaseModel):
    name: str
    address: str


class Employee(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    department: Department


@app.post(
    '/upload/',
    openapi_extra={
        'requestBody': {
            'content': {
                'application/json': {
                    'schema': Employee.schema(ref_template='#/components/schemas/{model}')
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
async def create_employee(employee: Employee):
    return employee


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Schema is broken with error:

> Resolver error at
> paths./create/.post.requestBody.content.application/json.schema.properties.department.$ref
> Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer:
> /components/schemas/Department does not exist in document

[image]

How to fix the error?

P.S. I'm trying to build the schema this way because I develop gateway service that redirects requests further but there is still need for schema in swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to override the default FastAPI class where needed schemas should be added to schema https://github.com/sector119/custom_openapi/blob/main/custom_openapi/applications.py#L9

Comment: That link is dead